# pass file path through cmd to python script

Tags: python, vb.net, cmd, argv

I am using vb.net and Arcobjects for my program. I am creating a button for ArcMap 10 that will convert a kml to a lyr file.

I am having problems passing variables into the python code. The variables are file paths and it works great if I hard code them in with / instead of . When the variables are dynamically passed in, the program breaks at the "/"s in the path names:

```
    Dim Filelocation As OpenFileDialog = New OpenFileDialog()

    Filelocation.Title = "Please point photo of the owner"
    Filelocation.InitialDirectory = "B:\GeoSpatialData\Projects\004402 Griffiths\File Structure\Geospatial\GPS\KML"

    If Filelocation.ShowDialog = DialogResult.OK Then
        Dim kmlFile As String
        kmlFile = Filelocation.FileName

        Dim args As String
        args = kmlFile & " " & kmlFile.Substring(0, kmlFile.LastIndexOf("\")) & " test"
        Dim args2 As String = args.Replace("\", "/")
        Dim procStartInfo As System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo = New System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo("C:\Python26\python", "C:\Users\KJacobsen\kml_to_shp.py " & args2)

        ' The following commands are needed to redirect the standard output.
        ' This means that it will be redirected to the Process.StandardOutput StreamReader.
        procStartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = True
        procStartInfo.UseShellExecute = False
        ' Do not create the black window.
        procStartInfo.CreateNoWindow = False

        ' Now you create a process, assign its ProcessStartInfo, and start it.
        Dim proc As New System.Diagnostics.Process()
        proc.StartInfo = procStartInfo
        proc.Start()
        proc.WaitForExit()

        ' Get the output into a string.
        Dim result As String = proc.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd()
        ' Display the command output.
        Console.WriteLine(result)
    End If
Catch objException As Exception
    ' Log the exception and errors.
    Console.WriteLine(objException.Message)
End Try
```

My python script looks like this:

```
import os
import arcpy
import sys
import glob
arcpy.KMLToLayer_conversion(sys.argv[1],sys.argv[2],sys.argv[3])
print
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace `"\"` to `"\\\"`

Does it work?

Comment: I replaced \ with /
 Dim args2 As String = args.Replace("\", "/")

Edited my code above.

Answer (score 0):

The path returned contains spaces? It seems so from your initial directory.
In that case the command arguments passed to the script could be wrong.

Try to enclose everything in double quotes and avoid direct manipulation of paths.
Use **Path.GetDirectoryName()** instead

```
Dim args As String         
args = """" + kmlFile + """ " 
args = args & """" & Path.GetDirectoryName(kmlFile) & """ test"
```